# Minikube MySQL files

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am running minikube on my mac using VB. I was able to start a database on minikube using declarative approach. But when I delete the deployment then data is lost. Now my questions are -

1. Where are all these data is saved?
2. How can I change the configuration so that the data is saved on the host (i mean mac)? That way deleting or restarting of pod/deployment won't delete all data.

Here is my yaml file -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: track-mysql
  labels:
    app: track
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: track
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
  labels:
    app: track
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: track-mysql
  labels:
    app: track
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: track
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: track
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: track
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc
```

I have checked, on my mac, the data is not on `/data/pv001`

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you delete the deployment kubernetes will delete all generated resources and all volumes as well.

You can [mount local folder](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/host_folder_mount.md)  and this way you will save your data to a local storage.

Because your persistent volumes are going to be deleted when you delete the deployment then in case you mount the local folder although volumes will be removed your data will be stored on local disk.

Comment: thanks. Ok that way I can mount a host folder, but when I `ssh` to minikube I don't see MySQL files on `/data/pv001`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you looking for files on your mac or inside the kubernetes. Inside it should be in mountPath: /var/lib/mysql , In host it should be in ~/mount-dir which you mount to minikube

Comment: I am looking into minikube. So what I do is `minikube ssh`, and then try to look for `/data/pv001` because that is the host path mentioned on the volume. And minikube is the host for kubernetes cluster. 

Also there is no mound dir so far, I didn't mount any mac folder into minikube so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was using postgresql and I found my data after running

```
minikube ssh
```

in a folder in this path

> /var/hostpath-provisioner/{my_namespace}/{my_claim_name}

Where

> my_claim_name

is basically

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
   name: my_claim_name
```

and namespace is just

```
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: my_namespace
  labels:
    name: my_namespace
```

although I couldn't cd into it cause I did not have root access